# Liquibase Installation Troubleshooting

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

Liquibase was install in the following location

C:\liquibase

when I run the following command on cmd,

```
liquibase
```

I get error

```
the system can not find specified path
```

I added liquibase to system variable

[image]

when I run the following command on cmd

```
java -version
```

The following output is displayed

```
java version "1.8.0_271"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_271-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.271-b09, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I also tried navigating to C:\liquibase and ran

```
liquibase --help
```

and the output was

```
the system can not find specified path
```

Any suggestion on what should be adjusted to run liquibase?

Answer (score 1):

After deleting JAVA_HOME variable that was set on user variables, the issue was fixed. See the following image that shows the user and system evironment variables, the user variable that was deleted is indicated surrounded by a red rectangle.

[image]

Comment: I was having the exact issue and this step resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `C:\liquibase` to your `Path` variable in order for `liquibase.bat` file (which is located in `C:\liquibase`) to be accessible from any location.

Comment: I added C:\liquibase to my path variable, still liquibase does not run.